# Drag and drop TXT file into TextArea

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, javafx, javafx-2

Here I have text area called sourceTx in which I drag and drop files, then I read content of that file with  BufferedReader. As you can see from bellow code I set file from which I am reading content with  absolutepath.

So, when I drag an drop some .txt file it works, it reads content and put it in text area, but when I also drag and drop some folder for example it also reads some content and put it in text area.

So I want set this drag and drop to read only .txt files? How I can get that?

Here is code of that method:

```
  public void dragDrop(){

       sourceTx.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler <DragEvent>()  {
        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {

            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();

            if(db.hasFiles()){
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);

                for(File file:db.getFiles()){
                    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(absolutePath)));

                        String line = null;
                        String text = "";

                        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n");

                        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                            text += line + nl;

                        sourceTx.setText( text.trim() );

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        MessageBox.show(MessageBoxType.ERROR, I18n.localize("File Error"), I18n.localize("Error while reading content from selected file"));
                    } finally{
                        if(br != null)
                            try {
                                br.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {}
                    }

                }

            }else{
                event.setDropCompleted(false);
            }

            event.consume();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can filter the file pathname.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but is there any similar example or something like that?

Comment: Well, you can look for many examples, but it is just a simple filter like `if (file.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().contains(".tif")) //proceed...`

Comment: Thanks, I ll try something like that.

Comment: Yes actually what @eee says is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there try to read your file with recursion

```
...
for (File file : db.getFiles()) {
    sourceTx.setText(handleFile(file));
}
...
    private String handleFile(File file) {
            String ret = "";
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                    ret.concat(handleFile(f));
                }
            } else {
                /*this is your filereader*/
                String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                BufferedReader br = null;
                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(absolutePath)));

                    String line = null;
                    String text = "";

                    String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n");

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                        text += line + nl;

                    ret.concat(text.trim());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    MessageBox.show(MessageBoxType.ERROR, I18n.localize("File Error"), I18n.localize("Error while reading content from selected file"));
                } finally {
                    if (br != null)
                        try {
                            br.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                }

            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good resource online on using drag and drop.
Here are some classes/things that you might want to investigate:

```
java.awt.dnd.*
```

I practically copied this from a tutorial online but here is some code (not mine, but tested and it works):

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    // insert other code here
    JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("My stuff here");
    // Create the drag and drop listener
    MyDragDropListener myDragDropListener = new MyDragDropListener(this);

    // Connect the label with a drag and drop listener
    new DropTarget(myLabel, myDragDropListener);

    // then just add the label
    // also have a method something like "get" which will be used so that the listener can send
    // the list of files dropped here, and you can process it here
}
```

Now for the MyDragDropListener.

```
import java.awt.dnd.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
public class MyDragDropListener implements DropTargetListener
{
    MyFrame frame; // initialize in a constructor that takes in the frame

    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent event)
    {
        // This is the main chunk of the drag and drop.
        event.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
        Transferable transferable = event.getTransferable();
        DataFlavor[] flavors = transferable.getTransferDataFlavors();
        for(DataFlavor flavor : flavors)
        {
            if(flavor.isFlavorJavaFileListType())
            {
                List myFiles = (List) transferable.getTransferData(flavor);
                frame.get(myFiles);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can use this to create a JFrame to drag and drop the files, then check if the filename contains ".txt" ( I am not sure if Java has methods of determining the type of file even if it has no extensions .) If it contains ".txt" then you can open it in the TextArea.

If anyone can please help me find the original tutorial/site, I would really appreciate it. Also sorry for the formatting of the answer.

Comment: Add a link to that good resource online on using drag and drop.